# Permissions and roles screen

Tags: roles, permissions

I'm creating a web scheduling system. I'm thinking if to have a screen with a table with permissions checkboxes for multiples entities (every entity on a row), eachone with permissions to read, write and delete is ok for UX.

I have checked another systems, and they have a simpler permissions system. My approach is very flexible, but maybe it can be tedious for user?

Answer (score 2):

If the set of permissions is a big list (10+), you can definitely go with table view.

A table view has the following benefits:

1. The entities are one below the other and easier to compare
2. It's also easier to scan the CRUD permissions (horizontally or vertically across roles)
3. The permissions would appear only once as header and it can even be made as a freezed row to improve accessibility.

Comment: Actually, I'm in doubt between setting CRUD permissions for each main entity (around 7 entities) or setting permissions in a simpler way, such as allowing only predefined profiles and let the user choose the profile he wants. The problem is that this takes away the flexibility of permissions. Permission set has 3 permissions (create and update will be merged into write): write, read and delete.

Answer (score 1):

As is often the case in UX, **it depends on the specific scenario**.

Some permissions could be really important (hence they need more control), while other may be trivial and you can use a lighter control.

However, there appears to be a problem with your approach: permissions are not intended to be treated as [CRUD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete) operations. They are essentially boolean and always exist. You either grant them or deny them, but you cannot delete or modify individual permissions at the user level. Such actions are reserved for system-level capabilities. Users can only interact with permissions in the manner I previously mentioned. The only exception is when dealing with permissions for third-party applications, where the option to delete the app entirely becomes available.

Comment: I meant set permissions to do CRUD operations with the entities, not to perform these operations on permissions themselves.